# ASHX Page Compilation Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, ashx

I have a simple .net site built in 4.5 and I have added one web service reference to a SOAP endpoint. The ASHX page works fine in visual studio test server but when I copy to server 2012 server I get this error:

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'QTWebService.VehicleInfo' is not defined.

I am confused because this type is contained inside the service reference. What am I doing wrong here?  The site runs fine with the dev web server but copy to server 2012 and boom.

Thanks

Comment: If you copy the relevant files from the `\bin` directory to the server, does it work?

Comment: there are not any files in the bin directory - for simple ashx I usually just copy the files over to the server and compile at runtime. I am not even sure I know how to compile. We may be on to something though,

Comment: When I publish the site this is all I get...https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1531272/Capture1.JPG

Comment: I was able to publish as a precompiled site and then copy the files - this produced a dll file. Still the same problem. It is like the class that came from the webservice reference is not accessible. I am not sure how this could be.